# How do I do to ask something in if/else structure?

Tags: python, if-statement

I am a very new beginner in python programming so I hope my question makes sense.

I want to make a program of a medical interview with guided questions depending on the user answers to previous questions.

I started with basic if/else structure but I am blocked because I don't know how to ask something in an if/else structure. For example :

```
A = input("Question 1 ? ")

if A == "yes":
    print("Consequence of yes to question 1")
else:
    A == "no"
    print("Consequence of no to question 1")

if A == "no":
    B = input("Question 2 ?")
```

It seems I can't put `input` statement in an `if` statement because when I run, it does not take the `B = input("Question 2 ?")` into account. But I need to assign a yes/no answer to Question 2 so I can pursue the interview. All I saw on the internet is `print` statements in if/else structure. I also tried to do *nested* `if` statements but it doesn't work.

Could someone help me please ?
Thanks a lot

Comment: There's no such restriction to what can appear inside the body of an `if`. I don't think I fully understand your question, but `else: A == "no"` should be `elif A == "no":` at the very least (or just `else:` unless you want to do checking to ensure that they didn't type nonsense).

Comment: What do you mean by "*does not take the B = input("Question 2 ?") into account.*"? Based on your code, the second question will only be *asked* when the answer to the first question is "no". What exactly if your intended flow here?

Comment: What I want to do is that if the answer to Q°1 is no, the program ask another Q°2 to which we I can answer yes or no. So the answer needs to be stored in a variable (called B in my previous example), and after according to the value of B, I ask another question or I conclude.

Comment: I mean when I run the program the question B is not displayed.

Comment: Seems like all you need to do is change to using `elif`, as some of the answers below suggest (this is the main bug in your code). However, I'm not able to reproduce what you're saying since the current code should print the input prompt for the 2nd question if you enter "no" for the first question...

Comment: Thank you for your answer, well I am tempted to post my "real" code (I simplified here with a, b, question 1 and 2) because all questions are written in french..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do an `elif` statement, it's `else` and `if` combined, so what it means is that if the first condition isn't true, check if this one is true:

```
A = input("Question 1 ? ")

if A == "yes":
    print("Consequence of yes to question 1")
elif A == "no":        
    print("Consequence of no to question 1")

if A == "no":
    B = input("Question 2 ?")
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, indeed with `elif` it is better

Answer (score 0):

I think someone beat me to it, but you should chain together your if statements to make things flow better.

```
a = input("Question 1 ? ")

if a == "yes":
    print("Consequence of yes to question 1")
elif a == "no":
    print("Consequence of no to question 1")
else:
    print('third statement')

b = input("Question 2 ?")

if b == "yes":
    print("Consequence of yes to question 2")
elif b == "no":
    print("Consequence of no to question 2")
else:
    print('third statement')
```

Since you're starting out and this is a pretty common track for people here's another tidbit for funzies. with your strings you can use the .lower() to make your user inputs a little more uniform. There is a lot you can do with strings to get the input standardized and hopefully this gets you rolling a bit.

```
a = input("Question 1 ? ")
##input into lowercase
a = a.lower()

if a == "yes":
    print("Consequence of yes to question 1")
elif a == "no":
    print("Consequence of no to question 1")
else:
    print('third statement')

b = input("Question 2 ?")
##input to lower case
b = b.lower()

if b == "yes":
    print("Consequence of yes to question 2")
elif b == "no":
    print("Consequence of no to question 2")
else:
    print('third statement')
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I want `b` to be linked to `a`. One of the consequence of question 1 has be to be `b = input("Question 2 ?")`, I succeed to do that but afer when I want to use `b` in a if statement I have an error `name 'b' is not defined`

Comment: Gotcha, U11 hit the nail on the head then. Just use elifs and you can chain together as much as you want.